# EntityManager not persisting cascading objects

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables Users, USER_ROLES, and APP_USERS_USER_ROLES. Created entity beans for Users and User_roles tables. In Dao object used EntityManager object, I tried set the UserRoles with User Object. User object got created. But corresponding rows in APP_USERS_USER_ROLES were not created. In the output you can observe that APP_USERS_USER_ROLES's SQL statements were not found.

What mistake did I do?

Tables:

```
create table USERS (
    userid BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    middle_name VARCHAR(64) default '',
    last_name  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    is_active ENUM ("1", "0") default 1,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_USERS (userid),
    UNIQUE UK_USERS_USERNAME (username),
    UNIQUE UK_USERS_EMAIL (email)
);

create table USER_ROLES (
    roleid BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    rolename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_USER_ROLES (roleid),
    UNIQUE UK_USER_ROLES (rolename)
);

CREATE TABLE APP_USERS_USER_ROLES (
    app_userid BIGINT NOT NULL,
    app_roleid BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY PK_APP_USERS_USER_ROLES (app_userid, app_roleid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_APP_USERS_USER_ROLES_USERID FOREIGN KEY (app_userid) REFERENCES USERS (userid),
    CONSTRAINT FK_APP_USERS_USER_ROLES_USERROLE FOREIGN KEY (app_roleid) REFERENCES USER_ROLES (roleid)
);
```

Entity Beans:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userid;

    ....

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<UserRoles> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRoles>();

    # Respective setters / getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="USER_ROLES")
public class UserRoles {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roleid;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "APP_USERS_USER_ROLES",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "APP_ROLEID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "APP_USERID")
    )
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User> ();

    # Respective getters & setters
}
```

Dao Implementation:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    ...

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        System.out.println("here " + user);
        if (user.getIsActive() == null) {
            user.setIsActive(YNFlag.Yes);
        } else if (user.getIsActive().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            em.remove(user);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set isactive to 'No' while adding a new user");
        }
        String passwordEncr = PasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncr);
        Set<UserRoles> userRoles = user.getUserRoles();
        user.setUserRoles(userRoles);
        em.persist(user);
        Logger logger = loggerCtx.getLogger(this.getClass());
        logger.info("User created: " + user);
    }

    ...
}
```

Output:

```
2017-Oct-01_17:35:01.142 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.r.t.springmvc.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl Entering method - addUser - with arguments - [{Userid: null, Username: dingdong2, First name: ASDF, Middle name: ASDF, Last name: ASDF, Role: ADMINISTRATOR, USER, Isactive: null, Password: asdfasdf, Email: asdf@rsa.com}]
here {Userid: null, Username: dingdong2, First name: ASDF, Middle name: ASDF, Last name: ASDF, Role: ADMINISTRATOR, USER, Isactive: null, Password: asdfasdf, Email: asdf@rsa.com}
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        USERS
        (email, first_name, is_active, last_name, middle_name, password, username) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
17:35:01.254 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.r.t.springmvc.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl - User created: {Userid: 14, Username: dingdong2, First name: ASDF, Middle name: ASDF, Last name: ASDF, Role: ADMINISTRATOR, USER, Isactive: Yes, Password: 4B2968E588D0630838676CD2F3D5159BA28FF77823D3FBE7B6C49DE44406D78517FEEEFEAEDB9FD6F11439132D40CEBAA16497C40510C5FCBDBFC03E03C85CB4, Email: asdf@rsa.com}
2017-Oct-01_17:35:01.254 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.r.t.springmvc.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl User created: {Userid: 14, Username: dingdong2, First name: ASDF, Middle name: ASDF, Last name: ASDF, Role: ADMINISTRATOR, USER, Isactive: Yes, Password: 4B2968E588D0630838676CD2F3D5159BA28FF77823D3FBE7B6C49DE44406D78517FEEEFEAEDB9FD6F11439132D40CEBAA16497C40510C5FCBDBFC03E03C85CB4, Email: asdf@rsa.com}
17:35:01.254 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  c.r.t.springmvc.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl - execution(UserDao.addUser(..)): 112 ms
```

Comment: The cascade option shouldn't be configured in the `User` entity since you saving the user?

Comment: Agreed with @araknoid: the `@ManyToMany` ownership should in the the `User` side with your Dao configuration

Comment: I swapped @ManyToMany between User and UserRoles entity beans. Now I got error org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.rsa.tools.springmvc.model.UserRoles.